# Using asp.net HTTPHandler to implement my own code and then calling its default implementation?

Tags: asp.net, http, httphandler, httpresponse

I am running into some problem, I created a type that I am using as a HTTPHandler for aspx in my web.config file, the code..

```
<add path="*.aspx" verb="*" type="myHandler"></add>
```

The cs page is

```
public class myHandler :  IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context) 
    {
        // check if client browser can accept gzip encoding
        string AcceptEncoding = context.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AcceptEncoding) && AcceptEncoding.Contains("gzip"))
        {
            // if yes, apply it
            context.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(context.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        }
        // don't do anything else, just let the default page handling work
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

}
```

As you can see, I am checking if the client accepts a gzip encoding, if yes, add it, and let the default process handle...
**BUT** the response I am getting is..

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://localhost:49903/Masters/Default.aspx
Line Number 1, Column 1:
^
```

every single page is returning this error? I am guessing that after I handled the request in my handler, it is somehow clearing everything else or something related.

Firebug shows the following..

```
Response Headers

Cache-Control   private
Connection  Close
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  0
Date    Sat, 06 Oct 2012 13:14:50 GMT
Server  ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319


Request Headers

Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  ASP.NET_SessionId=1wfoaqta3mosntii1c3ual1i; .ASPXAUTH=D41BBDC2CCF15048BB5A345EBBFBC63EAE35FD37E2F1F170C1D68495477889A989353D4EB30F2B9A723F83C21293A47478B654A1BD2453BCF032DC539427EA0E519D2FEE70DB7660F00AA90E159633C4
Host    localhost:49903
Referer http://localhost:49903/Masters/Default.aspx
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1


Request Headers From Upload Stream

Content-Length  8241
Content-Type    multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------2995119424827
```

So, from what I am guessing, I would like to know is there a way that after I have handled the page my way, I can do something like `base.ProcessRequest()`. I know its not possible, because I am implementing a interface and not deriving from a class, but I wanna know, how can I let the asp.net engine process the page after am I done with mine?

**NB** This question is not about implementing gzib encoding, I know I can set it in web config, at each page, in IIS, make a static function in a utility class and call it, and many other things. But again, please don't answer that I could use a different way to implement this gzip encoding, *I know I can*, what I am concerned is how can I let asp.net do its default handling (or whatever that may mean) after I am done with my custom handling?

Comment: HttpHandlers are not chained, so your code doesn't actually call any base behavior. The code you have doesn't produce any output.

It is possible to create a new instance of the Page class (which is the base ASPX handler) and then call that from your own handler. Works, but it's better to implement any pre/post processing with an HttpModule as Aristos describes in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You follow the wrong path. The handler you try to use is for make a totally different way for processing some kind of files ending in a different extensions, by adding the `.aspx` then you handle that page and not permit the asp.net processing the pages at all.

What you should do is to make an `httpModule`, eg a class like:

```
public class gZipModule : IHttpModule
{
    void IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
    }

    void IHttpModule.Dispose()
    {
    }

    private void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // gzip here
    }
}
```

and on web config:

```
<httpModules>
   <add type="gZipModule"  name="gZipModule" />
</httpModules>
```

or even more simple, on `global.asax` make at `Application_BeginRequest` the gZip

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // check if the file is .aspx, then make gzip
    string cTheFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;
    string sExtentionOfThisFile = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(cTheFile);

    if (sExtentionOfThisFile.Equals(".aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {   
        // now make gZip
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Application_BeginRequest` will execute once at the start of application, and the code inside it would only be reached just once. It can't be used for each and every page. Haven't tried the `IHttpModule.Init` though, will try tomo and let you know.

Comment: @Razort4x You have wrong - it will called, on every call. Check it out, read the manual.